Navigating a Powerpoint slideshow
I'm trying to create an AppleScript that allows me to jump to a specific slide in a running presentation. I tried a bunch of things, the latest being the following, but I'm alway getting errors.
I'm not at all at ease with AppleScript, any help would be much appreciated :)
Jay
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    activate
    
    if exists presentation 1 then
        tell presentation 1
            if not (exists slide show window 1) then
                run slide show 
            end if
            
            tell slide show view of slide show window 1
                go to slide (slides's item 5)
            end tell
        end tell
    else
        display dialog "No active presentations."
    end if
end tell


I'm not knowledgeable about powerpoint but I don't believe that you can. Go to slide seems to work with a document window but not with a slide show window. For example, the slide show window can be told to go to next slide but not go to slide. As well, it seems that slide and current show position are read-only. I guess they figure that the slide show is meant to be set before it begins — no freewheeling. That said, if you know in advance that you wish to skip a series of slides, you could create a 'custom show' which allows you to select and order the slides to be run.

I tried a bunch of other things, but came to the same conclusion... Thank you for taking the time :)
